# REGEX for finding the word that doesn't start with space or end with space

Tags: javascript, regex

consider the following string:

`"abc123 123 123abc abc123abc"`

Now i want to select 123 that is not by itself. So all digit but digit `\s\d+\s+`

I've tried ton of stuff but no..

Comment: How would you select it?

Answer (score 4):

So here is a short solution to your problem:

```
\B123|123\B
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/gMYvwFcEwncfuo0A)

`\B` matches non word boundaries. So before or after `123` a part of a word must be found.

This will match all 123 without the one that is standing alone.

**Edit 1:**

If `123` stands for a **sequence of digits** and `abc` for a **sequence of letters** you could try

```
[a-zA-Z]\d+|\d+[a-zA-Z]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/AQl36fgidJE13pzc)

Unfortunately for this solution you have to create matching groups to retrieve the digits. This is the regexp then

```
[a-zA-Z](\d+)|(\d+)[a-zA-Z]
```

Comment: i meant 123 and abc as dummy text..the numbers could be anything and of any size

Comment: Could you clarify this. Could 123 of any size but fix for one text or should it be a digit list? If 123 and abc are only dummies and I have 123456, is then 12345 a match?

Comment: @MuhammadUmer, please check my answer. I suppose, I've done what you were looking for.

Comment: @Danek, you guessing that he means 123 stands for dummy digits and abc for dummy text. But he wrote 123 is also a dummy text. Thats why I asked. Its not clear to me.

Comment: @wumpz, I suppose, he meant a dummy digit sequence as dummy text, because of this statement in his question: So all digit but digit \s\d+\s+. Moreover, his comment could be logically separated like the following: i meant (123) and (abc as dummy text)..(the numbers [123] could be anything and of any size)...

Answer (score 3):

The following regex will work in the specific case:

```
/\w+123\w+|\w+123|123\w+/
```

As in:

```
"abc123 123 123abc abc123abc".match(/\w+123\w+|\w+123|123\w+/g);
```

Will output:

```
["abc123", "123abc", "abc123abc"]
```

Assuming that `abc` and `123` are both obfuscations then you'll need to alter 123 in the regex to target your relevant case.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion in your case would be:

```
[^\s\d]+\d+[^\s\d]*|[^\s\d]*\d+[^\s\d]+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/lBQBvdYMJHkLGMrx)

Detailed explanation:

```
[^\s\d]+ // Represents one or more non-whitespace and non-digit character
\d+ // Represents one or more digit (your required sequence)
[^\s\d]* // Represents zero or more non-whitespace and non-digit characters
| // Represents logical OR operation
[^\s\d]* // Zero or more non-WS and non-digit
\d+ // Your sequence
[^\s\d]+ // One or more non-WS and non-digit
```

NOTE: `[^\s\d]*` entries are used for capturing the whole group in case of `abc123abc`.

**UPD**: In the current version, from the string `abc13 124233 356abc abc12333abc` my regex would match `abc13`, `356abc` and `abc12333abc`.

Also tested with [Rubular](http://rubular.com/).

Comment: the question is if "123-" should match or not. "-" could be a dummy text as well.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're looking for is the string of digits as a distinct word, regexp can use word boundaries.  For example:

```
$ echo "abc123 123 123abc abc123abc" | egrep -o '\<[[:digit:]]+\>'
123
```

Or perhaps a better example:

```
$ echo "abc123 234 345abc abc456abc" | egrep -o '\<[[:digit:]]+\>'
234
```

Now, I'm not a JavaScript guy.  But if as @wumpz seems to suggest, JavaScript's regex parser uses `\B` in place of `\<` and `\>` then a regex of `\B[[:digit:]]+\B` would seem to do the trick, assuming JavaScript understands classes.

Comment: I realize this isn't sufficient for a Best Answer (I know regex, I just don't know JavaScript), but if it helps you figure out a solution, then an upvote wouldn't hurt.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're looking for lookahead assertion and lookbehind assertion in regular expression.

```
[^\s]*(?<!\s)123(?!\s)[^\s]*

will match abc123abc only
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/wMdf3wb4RMzi3Sz5)

But the bad news is that javascript regular expression doesn't support lookahead/lookbehind assertion

Comment: As far as I know JavaScript does not support look behind expr.